# How to get attributes from java to jsp page

Tags: java, html, jsp, struts

**create_PaperAction.java**

```java
package Actions;

import Beans.create_paperBean;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.apache.struts.action.ActionForm;
import org.apache.struts.action.ActionForward;
import org.apache.struts.action.ActionMapping;

public class create_paperAction extends org.apache.struts.action.Action {

    @Override
    public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form,
            HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws Exception {

        create_paperBean val = (create_paperBean)form;        
        String result = val.createDB();
        request.setAttribute("table_name", val.getTable_name());
        return mapping.findForward(result);
    }
}
```

I'm using struts and this is page is forwarded to 
**createQues.jsp**
What i want to do is get the value of the setAttribute into an input text box on createQues.jsp. How do i do that?

Comment: You are using struts2 or earlier version???

Comment: @AnkitPanwar Struts 1.3 is deprecated as of EOL.

Comment: I'm totally new and was taught to begin with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get it like with Expression language.

```
  <input type="text" name="someX" value="${requestScope.table_name}">
```

Other wise the same thing with `scriplets`(Which is not recommended)

```
<%= (String) request.getAttribute ("Error_Message") %>
```

Comment: Scriplets are bad idea. Use EL.

Comment: As in, i want to put this value in a text type input box inside a form so that i can retrieve this value on a Struts ActionForm Bean.

Comment: @RohitJain My old damn habit :)

Comment: @sureshatta. You don't need `requestScope` too. Just `table_name` will be fine. It will search in all scopes.

Comment: @RohitJain Will it be redundant,If we not specify a scope ,Since we know that its in request scope ?? Correct me if I am going in wrong direction.

Comment: @sureshatta. If you are sure that it will be only in one scope, whatever it is, then you don't need to give scope explicitly. Since `EL` searches for the attribute in - `page`, `request`, `session`, `application` scopes in that order.

Comment: Sorry @RohitJain, if I'm extending this,But if we specify `request` then it skips the search in `page` scope ,Right ??

Comment: @sureshatta. Well, if you specify a scope, `request`, or `session`, it won't search in any other scopes. Just try to get the attribute from specified scope.

Comment: @RohitJain Yes,That's what exactly I thought .Thanks for the info :)

Comment: @sureshatta There should be another reason why not the scope is prefixed to the JSP variables.